# What are the right steps to work with php SOAP and WSDL?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have fixed many of issues and confusions, Please see

#### [Final Code and issue on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27147950/soap-issue-server-was-unable-to-process-request-gt-authentication-failed)

---

while developing PHP SOAP service (first time) I m facing many errors.

Let me draw the scenario to understand better & in my understandings

What I have on my hand

- A web url (`<weburl>.asmx`)
- 2 WSDL links

  - `<wsdlink>`  ==>  https :.../Schemas/Informationservice.WSDL
  - `<other_wsdlink>` ==>  https :.../Schemas/Orderuploadservice.WSDL
- 3 certificate files (`<cert>.pem` and `<cert>.CER` and `<cert>.PFX` )

From Reference of [PHP SOAP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.soap.php) , I have created this  [class](http://pastebin.com/3aCWMXeG)

**P.S.** this web service is on *ASP.net* and **SOAP 1.1** so run this with http**s**

below is the main code section

```
  $x = new SoapClient(<wsdlink>, [
                                // 'local_cert' => '<cert>.pem',
                                // 'allow_self_signed' => true,
                                // 'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
                                'location' =>'https://192.168.xx.xx/wsdl/try.php',
                                'uri' =><other_wsdlink>,
                                'passphrase' => $passphrase,
                                'exceptions' => false,
                                'trace' => true,
                                'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1
                                //'connection_timeout'=>2000,
                                //'encoding'=> 'ISO-8859-1' // 'UTF-8'
                            ]);
```

Here are 2 cases

---

#### 1. When I run this ( commented 3 lines) then it takes too much time to response and finally gives the error in XML,

- **Procedure 'requestedMethodRequest' not present.**
- **Function 'requestedMethod' doesn't exist.**

see the output

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<SOAP-ENV:Fault>
<faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
<faultstring>Procedure 'requestedMethodRequest' not present</faultstring>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

or sometimes ( by commenting few other options or chaning the uri ) it gives

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
        <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
        <faultstring>Function 'requestedMethod' doesn't exist</faultstring>
    </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

despite the fact that the function exist in the return [`SoapServer::getFunctions()`](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getfunctions.php)

```
Array
(
[0] => firstFunctionWithoutParam
[1] => secondFunctionWithoutParam
[2] => requestedMethodResponse RequestedMethod(requestedMethodRequest $messagePart)
[3] => secondFunctionClassParam
)
```

---

#### 2.When I un comment above 3 lines then gives multiple Warnings and FATAL Error

> **Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient():**
>
> ```
>   - Unable to set private key file <cert>.pem
>   - failed to create an SSL handle
>   - Failed to enable crypto
>   - (<wsdlink>):failed to open stream: operation failed
>   - I/O warning : failed to load external entity <wsdlink>
> ```
>
> **Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR:** 
>   Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from `<wsdlink>`:failed to load external entity `<wsdlink>`

I have searched and read various blogs for all errors and applied their suggestions but no luck so far. from one of [this blog](http://incarnated.net/blog/php-soap-server-procedure-not-present), I have deleted any temp file from `/tmp/wsdl*` and  wsdl cache disabled using `ini_set`

```
    ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0);
    ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);
```

My queries and confusions are :

1. Do I need to set up `soapClient` and `soapServer` both in constructor?
2. Do I need to set something extra rules for certificate file?
3. what does the `$uri` option do ( is that mandatory) and which is sending for the request  or
4. Is this a certificate issue or may be the system or network issue (**UBUNTU 14.04**), If it is then how do check this?

### update

change permission certificate

```
 openssl pkcs12 -in certificatefile.PFX -out certfile.pem -nodes -clcerts
```

and uncomment `cert` option and commented all `preg_replace` code from *__doRequest* method

but now **Header issue** raised. I notice that the request I sent is being trimmed or chopped off.

Request which I sent through [`SoapClient::__soapCall`](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php) is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
          <soap:Body>
            <addressVerificationRequest xmlns="urn:DCNZ.MSP.Wireline.Wholesale.Common">
              <addressVerification>
                <samId xmlns="urn:DCNZ.MSP.Wireline.Wholesale.Common">string</samId>
                ...
                <postalCode xmlns="urn:DCNZ.MSP.Wireline.Wholesale.Common">string</postalCode>
              </addressVerification>
            </addressVerificationRequest>
          </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>;
```

and `var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:DCNZ.MSP.Wireline.Wholesale.Messages">  
 <SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:addressVerificationRequest/></SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>'
```

above header issue fixed, it was generated cause of wrong `uri` value . It would be namespace

Comment: Seems like you're missing soapClient indeed. I always set it up in my constructor.

Comment: I have used  `parent::__construct($wsdl, $options);` and it's working that's why `var_dump($x->__getFunctions());` retun function list.

Comment: sad to see no comments, no response so far? are all moderator away from work?

Comment: Can you please share the wsdl file? Do you have access to the server logs? can you share the exception you are getting on the server side?

Comment: You meet a high-rep OP's question problem: nobody can answer it :-) I myself worked on web services but never met your issue; and without a reproducible case this will be difficult to help.

Comment: FYI, the link to your pastebin is dead.

Comment: You only need to use SoapServer if you intend to provide a service.  If you're just consuming a service, you only need SoapClient.  Why are you using SoapServer?

Comment: added pastebin link with original code

Comment: Sorry if I'm wrong but I'm a little confused with what you try to do. You are working in WSDL mode and setting a location pointing to your own php client code https://.../wsdl/try.php (you do not have a SoapServer, your class is not a server is a client) and uri pointing to a schema, that is wrong. In WSDL mode this two option parameters are optional, anyway, the location should point to the real webservice endpoint (the WSDL uri, https://.../WebServices/OOTInternal/Schemas/InformationService.wsdl in your case) and the uri should be the target namespace of the Webservice.

Comment: @vzamanillo Thank you for telling the whole thing.I am doing exactly what you understand. So `uri` would be the namespace and `location` would be *.wsdl* link. my main confusion is in this approach is the namespace. see in the code i tried with 2 namespace but still got issues. I would be very helpful if you set an demo on your end and show me.

Comment: and what about the certificate? can I work without any certificate?

Comment: No body is here is to help. everyone seems after reputations. Disgusting and highly disappointed

Comment: Did you set the trace option of the SoapClient object? Otherwise the method __getLastRequest() won't work.

Comment: Yes I did that's why it works. Please see the code class

Comment: The element addressVerification does not have a namespace.

Comment: __soapCall does not expect a complete SOAP message as second parameter, expects an arguments array for the mehod,if you want to send the body (only the body, not a complete message) as xml you should use a SoapVar in this way: $soapBody = new \SoapVar('<addressVerification>...</addressVerification>', \XSD_ANYXML);
$return = $this->client->__SoapCall('AddressVerification', array($soapBody));. You are disguested and dissapointed but you did not read the PHP documentation about SoapClient :/

Comment: @vzamanillo : I fix this error also. please see my final code with one error here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27147950/soap-issue-server-was-unable-to-process-request-gt-authentication-failed

Answer (score 0):

Any easy way to ensure you get the right classes in PHP is to use https://github.com/wsdl2phpgenerator/wsdl2phpgenerator they supply a command line generator that you can run with the WSDL that you have and it will generate you a bunch of PHP classes for all the requests and responses and most importantly the Service.

From your class where you are calling the webservice you can then do something like:

```
// Construct the service
$service = new Service();
// Construct the request
$request = new RequestMethod();
$request->element = "test";
// Call the function
$response = $service->callRequest($request);
// process response
die(var_dump($response));
```

You will likely have to refactor the generated classes if you are working with something like a framework, but it gives you a great starting point.