# PHP WSDL SOAP Issue: Server was unable to process request.; Authentication Failed

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

Having solved my [previous problem with SOAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26969389/what-are-the-right-steps-to-work-with-php-soap-and-wsdl), I now have a follow-up question. When I try to retrieve data from [WSDL service link](https://www.wirelineonboarding.co.nz/WebServices/OOTInternal/InformationService.asmx?op=AddressVerification) I got below error

> Server was unable to process request. ---> Authentication Failed

and my guess are

1. This is an issue with certificate

Please see below is the **`certificate.pem`** structure is

```
Bag Attributes
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICvTCCAiagA...vcNAQEEBhMCTlox
.....
.....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Bag Attributes
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----     
....
MIICvTCCAiagA...vcNAQEEBhMCTlox
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

2. I need to set [SoapHeader::SoapHeader](http://php.net/manual/en/soapheader.soapheader.php) But what to set? there is no such user authentication credentials. I have is one more certificate is in `.PFX` which was changed into .pem

and here is the main code

```
$wsdl = "https://<webservice>/Informationservice.WSDL";
$cert = getcwd().DS."certificate.pem";
$passphrase = "Wireline";
$uri = "https:///<webservice>/InformationService.asmx";
$namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";

$x = new SoapClient($wsdl, [
                                'local_cert' => $cert,
                                'passphrase' => $passphrase,
                                'allow_self_signed' => true,
                                'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
                                'location' => $uri,
                                'uri' => $namespace,
                                'exceptions' => false,
                                'trace' => true,
                                'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
                                'keep_alive' => true,
                                'connection_timeout'=>2000,
                                'encoding'=> 'UTF-8'
                            ]);

$req = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soap:Body>
        <addressVerificationRequest xmlns="urn:DCNZ.MSP.Wireline.Wholesale.Common">
          <addressVerification>
          ....
          </addressVerification>
        </addressVerificationRequest>
      </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';

$params = ['addressVerificationRequest' => (object)$req];
$x->__soapCall('AddressVerification',[$params]);


$responseHeaders = $client->__getLastResponseHeaders();
$response = $client->__getLastResponse();
```

---

**var_dump($responseHeaders);**

```
'HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Wed, 26 Nov 2014 10:54:33 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1203
```

**var_dump($response);** returns with multiple attributes in headers

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <soap:Header>
            <wsa:Action>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing/fault</wsa:Action>
            <wsa:MessageID>uuid:2db7b411-cabd-4716-aaaf-b5fac22efd21</wsa:MessageID>
            <wsa:RelatesTo>uuid:b4f10b7f-972c-4dbd-9ab2-a76a55d0322c</wsa:RelatesTo>
            <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
            <wsse:Security>
                <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-80353dc4-8a40-479e-9244-c7708df88ca8">
                    <wsu:Created>2014-11-26T10:48:56Z</wsu:Created>
                    <wsu:Expires>2014-11-26T10:53:56Z</wsu:Expires>
                </wsu:Timestamp>
            </wsse:Security>
        </soap:Header>
        <soap:Body>
            <soap:Fault>
                <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
                <faultstring>Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; Authentication Failed.</faultstring>
                <detail />
            </soap:Fault>

        </soap:Body>

</soap:Envelope>
```

Please suggest me the right fixes in the code. Here you can see the

> > [`complete code snippet`](http://pastebin.com/WRuDWk1T)

Comment: What's in the LocalSoapClient class?

Comment: Seems like you need to add WS-Security SOAP Header with Authentication (depends on the webservice provider, usernametoken, binarysecuritytoken... etc). The local_cert is for HTTPS client certificate authentication use only.

Comment: there is no username token etc credentials. that are not required at all ( AFAIK )

Comment: Question updated : added pastebin link